# Files not opening in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: nautilus, files

My Files are not opening in ubuntu and also not upgrading, whenever I restart the **nautilus** (that is default file manager in ubuntu) it gives me error below. I got help to chatGpt but it's not resolving my issue.

```
** Message: 14:05:00.689: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files

(org.gnome.Nautilus:85352): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 14:05:00.866: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' does not contain a key named 'migrated-gtk-settings'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Time to upgrade to 23.04. Support for 22.10 will expire very soon.